# Взаимодействия бэкенда и фронтенда

Tags: java, frontend, backend

Подскажите плз в общих чертах как взаимодействует фронт с бэком на примере какого нибудь динамического веб сайта, где есть фронт на JS и бэк на Java Spring. Должен ли фронт и бэк (REST API) запускаьться на разных портах/серверах? И потом их взаимодействие идет по http ? 
Как выглядит готовое приложение это два файла? .jar для бэка и .чтото для фронта? 
Спасибо за помощь.

Картинка ниже описывает суть моего вопроса.. Но как я понял из ответов вариантов архитектуры много.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]!

Comment: Лучше основную идею из скрина перенесите в часть вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В основном взаимодействие происходит на `HTTP` запросах (`GET`, `POST`, `DELETE` и т.д.).

Запускать на одном порту приложения или на разных - ну вопрос наверное, кому - как удобно. Для ухода от конфликтов, конечно же, приложения будут запущены на разных портах. По дефолту, вы заметите, что скорей всего ваше фронт приложение будет работать на `80` порту, а бекэнд на `8080`, если это `Tomcat`.

Готовое фронт приложение - это набор файлов (`HTML`,`JS`,`CSS` и т.д.). Готовое бекэнд приложение будет собрано в `war` или `jar` и запущено на сервере приложений.

Comment: А можно как то запустить 2 приложения на одном порту разве?

Comment: @IljaVeselov легко, если nginx поставить

Comment: Вариант когда бэк выдаёт сам страницы актуален? Или это для чего то очень простого?

Comment: Вполне актуален, все зависит от ваших требований. Посмотрите в сторону JavaEE, Spring. @IljaVeselov